# How to optimize parameters for binomial log-likelihood in python/scipy?

Tags: python, r, scipy, statsmodels, mle

I am converting some R code (not mine) for estimating the parameters of a choice model to Python. My Python version does not converge onto same parameters as the R version for some test data and I am not sure why.

The R code defines a log-likelihood function (L) and then uses the nlm() function to estimate the parameters:

```
L <- function(p, y1, m, i1, i0) 
     -sum(dbinom(y1, m, 1/(1 + i0 %*% p/i1 %*% p), log=TRUE)) 

out <- nlm(L, s, y1=y1, m=n, i1=idx1, i0=idx0)
```

For a set of test data this produces parameter estimates:

```
[1] 0.014302792 0.001703516 0.002347832 0.035365775 0.517465153 0.063503823 0.005776879
```

In python I have written (what I believe to be) an equivalent log-likelihood function (it returns the same values as R version for test parameters) and tried using scipy.optimize.minimize() in place of nlm():

```
def LL(p, *args):
    y1=args[0]
    m=args[1]
    i1=args[2]
    i0=args[3]

    i0p=np.dot(i0,p)
    i1p=np.dot(i1,p)
    P=1/(1 + np.divide(i0p,i1p))

    # y1 are observed successes in pairwise comparison experiment
    # m the number of trials, P the probability of success in one trial. 
    # I'm fairly sure these inputs are the same in python and R versions

    return -np.sum(stats.binom.logpmf(y1, m, P)) 


out = scipy.optimize.minimize(LL, s, args=(y1,n,idx1,idx0))
```

However, on running, minimize() seems to be unsuccessful:

```
out:
  status: 2
  success: False
  njev: 21
  nfev: 201
  hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
  fun: -273.75549396685
    x: array([ 0.14285714,  0.14285714,  0.14285714,  0.14285714,  0.14285714,
    0.14285714,  0.14285714])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
  jac: array([  27.99998093, -552.99998856, -500.49999237,  111.99997711,
    671.99995422,  255.49996948,  -14.00000381])
```

Other methods (e.g. 'Powell') report success but parameters are way off those from the example in R.

My questions are:

1. Elsewhere I've seen that 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.' is a result of badly behaved likelihood function - Can anyone tell is this is the case here? How might I fix it?
2. Should I try some of the other optimisation methods? They require derivatives to be passed to the minimise() method - How do I define the gradient (and if necessary hessian) for my LL function? I saw an example using statsmodel GenericLikelihoodModel but became confused about exog/endog...

Comment: I'm not good at reading R, but isn't that just the cross-entropy function for logistic regression? I.e. can't you use the logistic regression implementation in statsmodels?

Comment: try different starting values. As a check, you can use the values from R as starting values to see if your loglikelihood has a minimum there.

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example with data? More confusion about endog/exog...we're debating changing this, but it's a good bit of work. They just map to y/X in the usual linear model framework. You have a univariate problem.